# Scopia/Codian videoconference solution for Ubuntu?

Tags: sip, ekiga

I have Ubuntu at work and want to participate in visioconference/videoconferences with the [service provided by RENATER](https://renavisio.renater.fr/). This service is compatible with Scopia and Codian which are not ported to Ubuntu.

I tried the Ubuntu alternative software [Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/) but only the protocol h323 partially works, no SIP or direct IP address works. I managed once to see the other participants with h323/Ekiga, but they could not see me, and the other times nothing happens, the connexion does not even start.

There is no tutorial for my problem, so maybe AskUbuntu is the right place?